# Custom theme not Working on Wordpress multiple sites

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Install Network in WordPress for multi site and followed installation process from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

But now problem is that my custom theme is not working and also i can't see the add theme option.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/youcubed/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $ [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**WP-config**:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'socialgummers.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/demo/youcubed/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Comment: Do you have the theme in the correct folder (wp-content/themes/)?
Does it have the correct permission and owner?  Does the theme have a correctly formatted style.css file?